# Expression.Call GroupBy then Select and Count()?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Using Expression trees, I would need to build a GroupBy in a generic way.
The static method I'm going to use is the following:

```
public static IQueryable<Result> GroupBySelector<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, String coloumn)
{

  //Code here

}
```

The Result class has two property :

```
public string Value { get; set; }
public int Count { get; set; }
```

Basically I'd like to build the following Linq query via Expression trees:

```
query.GroupBy(s => s.Country).Select(p => new 
                {
                    Value = p.Key,
                    Count = p.Count()
                }
            )
```

How would you implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at:

```
query.GroupBy(s => s.Country).Select(p => new 
  {
    Value = p.Key,
    Count = p.Count()
  }
);
```

To match the signature of `IQueryable<Result>` what you actually need here is:

```
query.GroupBy(s => s.Country).Select(p => new 
  Result{
    Value = p.Key,
    Count = p.Count()
  }
);
```

Now, the `Select` can work with any `IQueryable<IGrouping<string, TSource>>` as is. It's only the `GroupBy` that needs us to use expression trees.

Our task here is to start with a type and a string that represents a property (that itself returns string) and create a `Expression<Func<TSource, string>>` that represents obtaining the value of that property.

So, let's produce the simple bit of the method first:

```
public static IQueryable<Result> GroupBySelector<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string column)
{
    Expression<Func<TSource, string>> keySelector = //Build tree here.

    return source.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(p => new Result{Value = p.Key, Count = p.Count()});
}
```

Okay. How to build the tree.

We're going to need a lambda that has a paramter of type `TSource`:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
```

We're going to need to obtain the property whose name matches `column`:

```
Expression.Property(param, column);
```

And the only logic needed in the lambda is simply to access that property:

```
Expression<Func<TSource, string>> keySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>
(
  Expression.Property(param, column),
  param
);
```

Putting it all together:

```
public static IQueryable<Result> GroupBySelector<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, String column)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    Expression<Func<TSource, string>> keySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>
    (
        Expression.Property(param, column),
        param
    );
    return source.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(p => new Result{Value = p.Key, Count = p.Count()});
}
```

About the only thing left is the exception-handling, which I normally don't include in an answer, but one part of this is worth paying attention to.

First the obvious null and empty checks:

```
public static IQueryable<Result> GroupBySelector<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, String column)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (column == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("column");
    if (column.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("column");
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    Expression<Func<TSource, string>> keySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>
    (
        Expression.Property(param, column),
        param
    );
    return source.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(p => new Result{Value = p.Key, Count = p.Count()});
}
```

Now, let's consider what happens if we pass a string for `column` that doesn't match a property of `TSource`. We get an `ArgumentException` with the message `Instance property '[Whatever you asked for]' is not defined for type '[Whatever the type is]'.` That's pretty much what we want in this case, so no issue.

If however we passed a string that did identify a property but where that property wasn't of type `string` we'd get something like `"Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for return type 'System.String'"`. That's not dreadful, but it's not great either. Let's be more explicit:

```
public static IQueryable<Result> GroupBySelector<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, String column)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (column == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("column");
    if (column.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("column");
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, column);
    if (prop.Type != typeof(string)) throw new ArgumentException("'" + column + "' identifies a property of type '" + prop.Type + "', not a string property.", "column");
    Expression<Func<TSource, string>> keySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>
    (
        prop,
        param
    );
    return source.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(p => new Result{Value = p.Key, Count = p.Count()});
}
```

If this method was internal the above would perhaps be over-kill, but if it was public the extra info would be well worth it if you came to debug it.

Comment: You have my vote, I posted a solution pretty similar which was downvoted without reason but anyways your answer is better than mine ;)

Comment: Whaw - that's a whole tutorial :) +1

Comment: @IvanStoev even questions that seem very narrow at first glance can offer opportunities for elucidation.