# Expression Tree Group and Select using Column with any Type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I'm using a variation of the code from the excellent thread below to dynamically build a treeview structure from any given data source using a custom list of columns.

[Expression.Call GroupBy then Select and Count()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35019869/expression-call-groupby-then-select-and-count)

My code is a recursive variation of the code presented in this solution:

```
public static List<MenuItem> GroupBySelector<TSource>(List<TSource> source, List<string> columns, int entry)
{
    string column = columns[entry];

    IQueryable<TSource> query = source.AsQueryable();

    int nextEntry = entry + 1;

    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (column == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("column");
    if (column.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("column");

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
    var prop = Expression.Property(param, column);

    Expression<Func<TSource, string>> keySelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, string>>
    (
        prop,
        param
    );

    if (columns.Count == nextEntry)
        return query.GroupBy(keySelector).Select(p => new MenuItem { Key = p.Key, Count = p.Count() }).ToList();
    else
        return query.GroupBy(keySelector)
          .Select(p => new MenuItem { Key = p.Key, Count = p.Count(), Items = GroupBySelector<TSource>(p.ToList(), columns, nextEntry) }).ToList();
}
```

While this is working perfectly for columns of a string type; how would I go about making this dynamically support columns of any (primitive) type? Including a list of columns that contains differing types - e.g Name(string), Age(int) etc.?

Comment: What will be the type of `MenuItem.Key` then? Or how should `int Age` be converted to string? What about `DateTime`, `double` etc.?

Comment: If you know the answers to @IvanStoev 's questions, you can build code to e.g. call `Convert.ChangeType` or `ToString` depending on what you need, but if your source is really a `List<>` why bother with using `Expression` and `IQueryable`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is possible, though pretty obscure. Once you start using runtime type information it tends to propagate outwards until you are compiling code at runtime, which fortunately isn't too difficult with `Expression` but it definitely is an area that could be improved in C#.

Here is my code:

```
public static class MenuItemTree {
    public static MethodInfo GetGenericMethod(this Type type, string name, Type[] generic_type_args, Type[] param_types) {
        foreach (MethodInfo m in type.GetMethods())
            if (m.Name == name) {
                var pa = m.GetParameters();
                if (pa.Length == param_types.Length) {
                    var c = m.MakeGenericMethod(generic_type_args);
                    if (c.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(param_types))
                        return c;
                }
            }
        return null;
    }

    static MethodInfo GetGroupByMethodStatically<TElement, TKey>()
        => typeof(Enumerable).GetGenericMethod("GroupBy", new[] { typeof(TElement), typeof(TKey) }, new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<TElement>), typeof(Func<TElement, TKey>) });

    static MethodInfo GetEnumerableMethod(string methodName, Type TTElement, Type TTKey) {
        var TIE = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(TTElement);
        var TF = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(TTElement, TTKey);
        return typeof(Enumerable).GetGenericMethod(methodName, new[] { TTElement, TTKey }, new[] { TIE, TF });
    }

    static MethodInfo GetEnumerableMethod(string methodName, Type TTElement) {
        var TIE = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(TTElement);
        return typeof(Enumerable).GetGenericMethod(methodName, new[] { TTElement }, new[] { TIE });
    }

    public static List<MenuItem> GroupBySelector<TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement> source, IList<string> columnNames, int entry = 0) {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        string columnName = columnNames[entry];

        if (columnName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(columnName));
        if (columnName.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(columnName));

        int nextEntry = entry + 1;

        var TTElement = typeof(TElement);
        var TIETElement = typeof(IEnumerable<TElement>);

        var keyParm = Expression.Parameter(TTElement);
        var prop = Expression.Property(keyParm, columnName);

        var parm = Expression.Parameter(TIETElement, "p");
        var gbmi = GetEnumerableMethod("GroupBy", TTElement, prop.Type);
        var gbExpr = Expression.Lambda(prop, keyParm);
        var body = Expression.Call(gbmi, parm, gbExpr);

        var TSelectInput = typeof(IGrouping<,>).MakeGenericType(prop.Type, TTElement);
        var separm = Expression.Parameter(TSelectInput, "p");

        var miKey = typeof(MenuItem).GetMember("Key").Single();
        var miCount = typeof(MenuItem).GetMember("Count").Single();
        var miItems = typeof(MenuItem).GetMember("Items").Single();

        Expression sepKey = Expression.Property(separm, "Key");
        if (sepKey.Type != typeof(string)) {
            var ctmi = sepKey.Type.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
            sepKey = Expression.Call(sepKey, ctmi);
        }
        var countmi = GetEnumerableMethod("Count", TTElement);
        var sepCount = Expression.Call(countmi, separm);

        var gbsmi = GetGenericMethod(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType, "GroupBySelector", new[] { TTElement }, new[] { TIETElement, typeof(IList<string>), typeof(int) });
        var sepItems = Expression.Call(gbsmi, separm, Expression.Constant(columnNames), Expression.Constant(nextEntry));

        var senew = Expression.New(typeof(MenuItem));

        var se1body = Expression.MemberInit(senew, new[] {
                        Expression.Bind(miKey, sepKey),
                        Expression.Bind(miCount, sepCount),
                        Expression.Bind(miItems, sepItems)
                    });
        var se1 = Expression.Lambda(se1body, separm);

        var se2body = Expression.MemberInit(senew, new[] {
                        Expression.Bind(miKey, sepKey),
                        Expression.Bind(miCount, sepCount)
                    });
        var se2 = Expression.Lambda(se2body, separm);

        var smi = GetEnumerableMethod("Select", TSelectInput, typeof(MenuItem));
        body = Expression.Call(smi, body, (nextEntry < columnNames.Count) ? se1: se2);

        var lmi = GetEnumerableMethod("ToList", typeof(MenuItem));
        body = Expression.Call(lmi, body);

        var returnFunc = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<TElement>, List<MenuItem>>>(body, parm).Compile();
        return returnFunc(source);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks! Definitely more complex than I was expecting, I'd never have got there myself.

Comment: @DaveW Thinking about it, there may be a way to use a generic lambda to simplify this. Or suggest an addition to C# for it :)